# What is the problem here , i am learning spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-data, boot

```
@PostMapping("/addStudent")
String addStudent(@ModelAttribute ("student")Students student,  Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("fname", fname);
    model.addAttribute("lname", lname);
    model.addAttribute("dob", dob);
    model.addAttribute("mobile", mobile);
    model.addAttribute("address", address);
    
    Students student = new Students();
    
    student.setFname(fname);
    student.setLname(lname);
    student.setDob(dob);
    student.setMobile(mobile);
    student.setAddress(address);
    
     studentsRepository.save(student);
    
    
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Here i am getting error that fname , lname , etc cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Well, have you defined them as variable somewhere in this class?

Comment: you are using ModelAttribute  no need to again  model.addAttribute remove everything except  studentsRepository.save(student);

Comment: 'public class Students {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
 private String fname;
 private String lname;
 private String address;
 private String dob;
 private String mobile;'

Comment: And is the addStudent method in the Students class as well, or is it in a different class?